# Java threading with the play framework is the math correct

Tags: java, multithreading, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am using the play framework as an api so essentially all of the requests are blocking jdbc calls. If we assume that I have all the hardware and everything else and that **each blocking request takes 250ms so then 1 thread can handle 4 blocking requests per second**, given this set up and I am using the new version of play 2.4.3. Thanks for reading

```
play { 
    akka { 
        akka.loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"] 
        loglevel = WARNING 
        actor { 
            default-dispatcher = { 
                fork-join-executor { 
                    parallelism-min = 300 
                    parallelism-max = 300 
                } 
            }
        } 
    }
 }
```

We can have up to 300 threads so (300*4)= 1,200 threads per second correct ?

If so does the parallelism-factor change anything at all from this?

If my thinking is correct then the only way to improve threads per second is to reduce the request blocking times and/or to increase the amount of threads, if so then to what amount can I safely increase the parallelism-max count in play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/configuration.html

```
    # The parallelism factor is used to determine thread pool size using the
    # following formula: ceil(available processors * factor). Resulting size
    # is then bounded by the parallelism-min and parallelism-max values.
```

Means that having min and max defined as 300 overrides anything you set via `parallelism-factor` as the only valid valid becomes exactly 300.

And yes, 300 concurrent connections limited to 4 requests per second each result in 1200 requests per second in total. But that's not a realistic way to go about finding values since database performance scales with load. You'll have to test whether more concurrent connections will result in an overall gain or not.

> If my thinking is correct then the only way to improve threads per second is to reduce the request blocking times and/or to increase the amount of threads,

Yes.

> if so to what amount can you safely increase the parallelism-max count in play?

Depends on your hardware. It's unlimited if your hardware is unlimited as well. In practice, look at the cpu load / memory consumption / (network bandwidth if db isn't on localhost) / (general io limits)  if and cap it out as much as you can. Using a factor is most likely simpler than defining fixed values.

Comment: Perfect thanks a lot, I will use the factor then since it is simpler.